# Python: Merge list of lists with boolean item?

Tags: python, list, merge

here i need to merge list of lists with a boolean item.

> Input like this

```
list = [[[3, [1, 2]]], [[1, [2, 3]]], False, [[4, [4, 5]]]]
```

> And excepted result is

```
[[3, [1, 2]], [1, [2, 3]], False, [4, [4, 5]]]
```

> I tried this

```
res = []
for x in list:
   res.append(x)
print res
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: take a look a this  [flatten (an irregular) list of lists in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python) any of the answers can be modify to only one level of nesting

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension to preserve the first element of your sub lists if they are valid (`if sub`) otherwise the sub list itself:

```
>>> lst = [[[3, [1, 2]]], [[1, [2, 3]]], False, [[4, [4, 5]]]]
>>> [sub[0] if sub else sub for sub in lst]
[[3, [1, 2]], [1, [2, 3]], False, [4, [4, 5]]]
```

*Note* : Don't use python keywords and built-in type's names as your variables and object names.

As @Padraic Cunningham suggested, for a more precise way you can use `isinstance()`:

```
>>> [sub[0] if isinstance(sub, list) else sub for sub in lst]
[[3, [1, 2]], [1, [2, 3]], False, [4, [4, 5]]]
```

Comment: What if there's a `True` in the list?

Comment: @kfx In that case we need to check it too. There might be a lot of scenario here but we are dealing with this one.

Comment: `if isinstance(...` would be better as  if sub  will return false positives

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes that's better, thanks for suggestion.